# How to let gnome-terminal to use specific font to display punctuations in their full width forms? (·‘’“”)

Tags: linux, fonts, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator

I'd like to use [SimSun(宋体)](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=868) font to display [interpunct/middle dot `·`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct), [single quotes (curly) `‘’`, double quotes (curly) `“”`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) characters in their [full width forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms), because it's easy to distinguish them from `.`(dot) `'`(single quote) `"`(double quote), and such distinguishable visibility is especially useful when typing code using input method, because input method can input ·‘’“” characters easily and made the code can't be compiled (`char *str=“will not compile”;`).

In gedit and geany and leafpad editor, set font to SimSun will make it work as expected.

[image: Geany editor, SimSun font, full width forms]

However in gnome-terminal, set font to SimSun does not get expected result. It *seems* gnome-terminal use another font to display their half width forms, or it *seems* they're just crowded together.

[image: gnome-terminal, SimSun font, half width forms]

I also tried lxterminal(LXDE) and Terminal(xfce) and ROXTerm, they displayed as the same as gnome-terminal did.

How to let these terminal emulators display punctuations in their full width forms like Geany does?

**Sample text**

```
1234567890
·“”‘’
```

**Unicode code points (HEX)**

```
   UTF16  UTF8
· 00B7   C2B7
‘ 2018   E28098
’ 2019   E28099
“ 201C   E2809C
” 201D   E2809D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older versions of gnome-terminal, you should export a `VTE_CJK_WIDTH=wide` variable before starting the first gnome-terminal instance.

Newer versions of gnome-terminal (probably as of 3.12 or 3.14) moved this to a UI setting: Profile preferences -> Compatibility -> Ambiguous-width characters: Narrow (default) or Wide (what you're looking for).

Note that whatever complex application (e.g. text editor) you're running inside your terminal should also be notified about this change, otherwise it'll have false assuptions about the cursor's location and the display will likely fall apart. I'm not aware of a generic method for this (there could/should be a locale where wcwidth() returns 2 for these characters rather than 1, but I don't think there's any), so you'll have to configure each app separately (if they have such a config option at all). Simple utilities that don't care about the cursor, e.g. a `cat` command should work without modification.

Comment: And to clarify: in gnome-terminal the width of a character (whether it occupies one or two cells) is never derived from the font.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! The UI setting in newer version of `gnome-terminal` works well (although it requires opening a new instance).  `VTE_CJK_WIDTH=wide` works for some other terminals, including `lxterminal` `lilyterm`, but not `mate-terminal` - the one from MATE Desktop (which is derived from GNOME2).

Comment: **It looks there's a bug in bash, when VTE_CJK_WIDTH=wide: If I pasted  `·“”‘’` in bash command line,I can't move the cursor back to home of command line input,  I can only move the cursor back to the middle of of `·“”‘’`**

Comment: This is not a bug in bash per se. Every application that does cursor positioning needs to know about the change. You might have missed this in my answer, or didn't think that bash also belons to this category. I don't think bash supports this, and I'm not sure if this feature should belong to bash or the locale system. Unfortunately, with this settings you're restricted to utilities that produce some continuous output flow without caring about the cursor position, and apps that do cursor movement but can handle the ambiguous-width characters being double-wide.

Comment: If I run `vim` from bash command line, vim can handle the full width form correctly (both displaying and cursor moving), `cat` is acting like bash.

Comment: I meant `cat` as in `cat sometextfile`. You probably refer to a lone `cat` and typing stuff and erasing that. That's again a whole different story, the kernel's responsibility which doesn't understand double-wide characters at all (not even CJK which are always double-wide).

Comment: Yes, I was typing/pasting some characters then use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key to delete them. That's a sad news to me, and make me missing Windows much - Windows did a very good job in localization/internationalization. Some others applications does not works well too, such as weechat, htop ... screenshots: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aHfNu.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/lV8tS.png

Comment: Apparently, unfortunately this ambiguous==wide story is not well supported inside terminals. Gnome-terminal itself is prepared for this, but it's not complete without support from apps (and the underlying locale system). Maybe you can revert to ambiguous==narrow setting and get used to that? Note however that we're only talking about terminals and terminal applications; graphical apps should be okay.

Comment: I've found this issue requesting locale definitions where these characters are wide: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4335. Unfortunately it's not resolved yet.

Comment: If you're brave enough, you could (on your own risk!) experiment with creating such a locale for yourself. I think you'd need to modify `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps/UTF-8.gz` (near the end of the file), and then run `localedef` or `locale-gen` to regenerate your locales.

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 Advanced terminal handling apps like bash, weechat, etc, may be able to handle things better if you set the locale (LANG or LC_CTYPE) correctly. For cat or other such programs, if you've made a mess of the input line with backspace you can press ^R to have it reprint its idea of what's in the partial input line on the next line.